# When to use variables?

Tags: javascript

I've started to learn HTML/CSS/JS after several years of no coding at all, previously some simple C++/Python/Pascal stuff.

In one of the tutorials, there is a very simple game to do, comparing a user input with a generated random number and displaying a message if both match.

The question is what is a general practice in web-development:

```
<p>How many fingers am i holding up?</p>
<input id=userInput type=text>
<input id=guessButton type="button" value=Guess!>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("guessButton").onclick=function(){

        if (document.getElementById("userInput").value == Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1)    

        alert ("You've won");
    }
</script>
```

vs

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("guessButton").onclick=function(){

    var numberGuessed=document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var randomNumber=(Math.random()*5);
    randomNumber=Math.floor(randomNumber)+1; 

        if (numberGuessed==randomNumber)            
        alert ("You've won");
    }
</script>
```

I get that this example is VERY simple, but when it comes to more complicated logic or nested functions is it better to strive for step-by-step clarity or to avoid the creation of unnecessary variables?

Comment: The priority is having readable code. You want the next guy to know what the code is doing without trying too hard. The amount of time saved for the maintainer will always outweigh the amount of time saved by the micro-optimization.

Comment: Aside: I think readable code is far more important than making your code run an extremely tiny fraction faster (depending on what you're building). Clean code > micro-optimisations. Although others may disagree, and this comment also makes the assumption that the variables approach looks cleaner (which it doesn't always).

Comment: To close-voters: this question is neither too broad, nor opinion-based. The fact that there are different ways to do something does not in itself make a question too broad or opinion-based. There can still be good answers to such questions, which point out the pros and cons of the different approaches.

Answer (score 3):

### Which is *faster*?

The answer to this one is it doesn't really matter a whole lot. If it's extremely necessary, for the best speed (both downloading off of the internet and running), if you're only using the values once, you'll want no variables. If you're using the values more than once, you'll probably want to define them in a variable. When downloading, the less data, the better. If you're only using it once, defining it as a variable would *technically* require more data to be downloaded (i.e. an extra `var`, an extra semicolon maybe), but it's so insignificant it should not be taken into account most of the time. Your Javascript took less than 1/10th of a millisecond to execute, so this should not be a concern most of the time, either.

### Which is *preferred*?

This is more of an opinion-based question, and therefore, not exactly allowed on Stack Overflow, but I think I can safely say that most developers would say what is important is readability. If this means defining the variables, then so be it. If code cannot be read easily, then it's going to be extremely difficult to expand and modify it, even for yourself, down the road. Readability is especially important when working in a team. Ultimately, though, you should do whatever you prefer.

Comment: The download speed is less of an issue if you use a [minification tool](https://jscompress.com/) before putting the code in production.

Answer (score 2):

For speed, as people have stated, the difference is negligible. As for best practice, the second is, in my opinion, demonstrably better.

If someone else is using your code, proper variable naming removes the question of "What are they trying to do?" from the list of problems another developer (or you in a few months) has to solve. Expressive variable names make it so that, If I'm trying to debug a function, I can focus my energy on what's "going wrong", not on what's "going on".

In your second code example, without even looking at how your variables are declared, I can instantly understand what you're **trying** to do, whether it's working as intended or not. I can then put a debugger before the conditional and check that all the values of the variables you've declared make sense based on what you've named them. For example, I can pretty quickly narrow down what might be wrong if one them is a string, `null`, `NaN`, or `undefined`.

The second example, however, forces me to evaluate **what** you're doing before I can analyze **how** you're doing it.

It's a similar philosophy to code comments, really, the smaller the ratio of time spent understanding vs debugging, the more maintainable the code will be.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those style questions for which you'll likely get a gazillion answers. I would prefer the in-line version *unless* I was going to use the values more than once. There is probably a tiny difference in performance, since you're having to add names to the local namespace and then (eventually) gc them, but I doubt that difference could be measured in any reasonable use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can break down a computation into intermediate variables, and this has the advantage not only of readability, but also of debuggability, since that lets you set breakpoints on each line where something is calculated, and examine the values of the variables.

However, you can also pre-calculate variables. In your case, the DOM element will never change, and so it can be pre-calculated outside the event handler:

```
const userInputElement = document.getElementById("userInput");

document.getElementById("guessButton").onclick=function() {
  var numberGuessed = userInputElement.value;
  var randomNumber=(Math.random()*5);
  randomNumber=Math.floor(randomNumber)+1; 

  if (numberGuessed==randomNumber)            
    alert ("You've won");
};
```

`userInputElement` needs to not be executed until the DOM is loaded. So this JS should be either at the end of your `body`, or wrapped in an event handler such as `DOMContentLoaded`.

Breaking the calculation of the random number down into two steps is probably going overboard. Most programmers would write this in one line:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
```

In this case, another option is to write this as a little separate function. This has several advantages. First, you would be able to re-use that function in other places in your code. Second, you could test it more easily in isolation. Third, the code where you are using it is simplified.

```
function getRandomNumber(n) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * n) + 1;
}
```

Now you can simplify your event handler to

```
document.getElementById("guessButton").onclick=function() {
  var numberGuessed = userInputElement.value;
  var randomNumber = getRandomNumber(5);

  if (numberGuessed == randomNumber)            
    alert ("You've won");
};
```

However, now that you have both pre-calculated the DOM element, and moved the random number calculation into a function, there is less need to calculate variables one-by-one in your event handler, and you can simplify it to:

```
document.getElementById("guessButton").onclick = function() {
  if (userInputElement.value == getRandomNumber(5))
    alert ("You've won");
};
```

Now you have a very simple, readable event handler, which anyone can look at and easily see what is happening. You also have a separate, re-usable random number generator.

Although not directly related to your question, I would strongly recommend that you indent your code properly, and also adhere to style guidelines for things like the use of spaces.

It is also recommended to use `addEventListener` instead of assigning to the element's `onlick` attribute:

```
document.getElementById("guessButton").addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (userInputElement.value == getRandomNumber(5))
    alert ("You've won");
});
```